# Why did my reputation decrease overnight?

Tags: support, voting, reputation

I filled out my profile information after achieving a reputation of nearly 200 and as I saved the changes, all of a sudden my reputation dropped(in the parent site) to 25! I checked my rep page and it seemed to have forgotten all my answers and such. It did however keep one of my answers that was chosen and one that got upvoted(maybe recently) as well as the one down vote I received.

Comment: Actually, my questions are still there, but all the votes on them were removed.

Answer (score 4):

Your reputation looks correct to me..

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1125/

have you tried going to

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation

to see the report?

Ah, I see -- looks like the daily voting anomaly script reset a bunch of anomalous votes on your account.